# Azure DevOps: How do you link work items to an existing build?

Tags: azure-devops

How can you add work to a PR often it's been opened and linked to another ticket?

Answer (score 1):

1. For the selected work item, Under the “Development” section, click on “Add Link“
2. From the "Add link dialog", choose one of the build link types
   - Build
   - Found in build
   - Integrated in build
3. Specify the build number once you select the “Link Type” for the build
4. "Find Build Dialog" allows us to find a specific build with build number or based on the respective pipeline. You can also search for specific build within a given date range, or based on the status of the build.
5. Select the Build, and click OK to link the Azure DevOps Work Item to an existing build.

You can add only on build reference with your work item. In case you want to attach a different build, you need to remove the existing one first.